# when case is queue user cannot send email

Tags: trigger, emailmessage

i am trying to restrict send email from trigger on emailMessage object when case assign to queue but its throw an error in my class  **Invalid field RelatedToId for SObject EmailMessage**

```
 public static void qCa(List<EmailMessage> eM){
    for(case cs:[select id,owner.type,ownerid from case where Ownerid in : eM[0].RelatedToId]) {
        if(cs.owner.type=='Queue') {
          cs.addError('You cannot send email if case is assigned to queue');
        }
   }

}
```

Comment: You're using `IN` with a singleton variable. I mean `eM[0].RelatedToId` is not of type collection. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes you are correct